# How to Pass Parameter with form.Activate(); instead of form.Show();

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

In the General Ledger, when user double clicks on the dgv row, The Purchase Invoice Form opens with relevent Purchase Invoices. If the Purchase Invoice is already open in MDIPARENT, it will just activated, for this scenario i apply the check

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  string invNo = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
  foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
  {
    if (f.GetType() == typeof(PurchaseForm ))
    {
      f.Visible = true;
      f.Activate();
      .....
    }
   ....
  }
  ....
}
```

I want to pass the parameter

---

```
 PurchaseForm form = new PurchaseForm();
 form.btnNewInvoice.PerformClick();
 form.txtInvoiceNo.Text = invNo;
 form.dataGridView1.Focus();
```

---

Its not working and not able to pass PARAMETER, Whats The Solution For This ???

```
   return;
        }
   }

   PurchaseForm form = new PurchaseForm();
   form.MdiParent = MainForm.ActiveForm;
   form.Show();

   form.btnNewInvoice.PerformClick();
   form.txtInvoiceNo.Text = invNo;
   form.dataGridView1.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Just add a constructor or a public method to the form class that lets you pass whatever you want.

Comment: You really shouldn't have the controls on your form public, and they shouldn't be messed with by another external class; the form should simply expose methods/properties that allow only the functionality that external callers need to perform to be invoked, and then the form itself should worry about the manipulation of it's internal controls; they should be an implementation detail, not a part of the public API.  Also, rather than finding the form in `openforms` just have a private field with the instance of the form that you've opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but it seems to me that you want to perform this code:

```
form.btnNewInvoice.PerformClick();
form.txtInvoiceNo.Text = invNo;
form.dataGridView1.Focus();
```

for when the form is already open.  You say that, "Its not working and not able to pass PARAMETER".  Most likely you are trying to use "f" in the snippet below?

```
if (f.GetType() == typeof(PurchaseForm ))
{
  f.Visible = true;
  f.Activate();
  .....
}
```

If so, just cast "f" to PurchaseForm like this:

```
if (f.GetType() == typeof(PurchaseForm ))
{
  PurchaseForm pf = (PurchaseForm)f;

  pf.btnNewInvoice.PerformClick();
  pf.txtInvoiceNo.Text = invNo;
  pf.dataGridView1.Focus();

  pf.Visible = true;
  pf.Activate();
  .....
}
```

EDIT: Simple example of what Servy is talking about...

Basically you'd create a public method to receive the invoice number.  That method can access the controls and set values directly.  Something like this:

```
public partial class PurchaseForm : Form
{

    public void SetInvoiceNumber(string invNo)
    {
        this.Visible = true;
        this.Activate();

        this.txtInvoiceNo.Text = invNo;
        this.btnNewInvoice.PerformClick();
        this.dataGridView1.Focus();
    }

}
```

Then, after casting "f" to PurchaseForm (as shown previously), you'd just do:

```
if (f.GetType() == typeof(PurchaseForm ))
{
  PurchaseForm pf = (PurchaseForm)f;
  pf.SetInvoiceNumber(invNo);
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I agree with Servy's comments above, though.  It's a bad design.

Comment: Whats the other way to do this, if you have better idea please tell me .